# Native Token Price Displayed wrong on Metamask

Tags: metamask

Mainnet native token is showing wrong price to all metamask useres for GOLDXCHAIN, it is new chain, token not even launched but looks like it is fetching ETH Price

Comment: Sometimes it is a problem of front end, it doesn't change when we change the network.